# Mysql Query: Need to totalize monthly given order number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table in which the last two rows are month and year respectively

[image: orders]

where idalbaran is equivalent to an order number.
Now, in another table I have the details of these orders, the table looks like this:

[image: order_details]

the last two rows are price and quantity

using mysql and php I need to obtain a list that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you need to do for your job!

Comment: Sorry, you need to show own effort on SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the MySQL part:

```
SELECT 
    idcliente,
    mes AS month,
    anio AS year, 
    SUM(precio*candidad) AS totalSoldToThatClientThatMonth
FROM client_table CT
    JOIN orders_table OT
      ON CT.idalbaran = OT.idalbaran
GROUP BY idcliente, mes, anio
```

I assume the first table's name is `client_table`, and the second name is `orders_table`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ft.idcliente, ft.mes, ft.anio,
sum(st.precio*st.cantidad) as Total
from firsTable ft
inner join secondTable st
on (st.idalbaram = ft.idalbaran)
group by ft.idcliente, ft.mes,ft.anio
```